# Signal handler function catches SIGKILL the first 3 times

Tags: c, unix, signals, handler, sigkill

I have an assignment to write a signal handler function that catches the SIGKILL signal and displays error messages the first 3 times it is called. On the 4th time that it handles a SIGKILL, it should set the signal handler to default and then send out SIGKILL to its process (which it will not catch).

I guess to use a loop and display the error messages in the first 3 iterations. Am I right? I have difficult to send SIGKILL to its process and set the handler to the default (which confuses me).

Can you give me advices?

Answer (score 11):

According to `man 7 signal`,

```
The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.
```

Answer (score 5):

what he said is true you cannot catch SIGKILL ans SIGSTOP

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void funCatch(int signal)
{
    printf("sucessfully caught the kill signal\n");
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    if(signal(SIGKILL,funCatch)==SIG_ERR)
    {
        printf("cannot catch signal\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is a sample code to verify the above statement.

Comment: Using `perror` instead of a simple `printf` would show that `errno` is set to `EINVAL` ("Invalid argument"). `sigaction` behaves similarly BTW.